# Hibernate Delete an entry/row when system time is equal to value in a field

Tags: java, hibernate, triggers

I have a field in my DAO which stores a future timestamp value. I want to delete the row from the table once system time reaches this particular value. What are the possible ways to do that? Specifically, I am looking for something similar to trigger on that field which is based on condition that when system_time=value in this field, then call delete for this particular entry/row/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database can not handle such scheduling or time based tasks, not even triggers. You have to do that in your application code and there are numerous ways to do that - one possible way to do this is to have that row values stored in memory (in any suitable structure) and have a background thread that periodically checks for time match. If time matches, go ahead and delete the row, else do nothing against this particular row. You can also consider using scheduling apis like Quartz etc.

Comment: Thanks Syed for your reply! For the in-memory storage option, it might be good for small set of data but if I will have huge amount of data, then it might be not a good way to go forward. Regarding Quartz or other scheduling apis, I am not that much familiar with so I am exploring these possibilities. Will get back to this post if have more questions.Thanks.

Comment: In Quartz, for each row/entry in the table I have to define a quartz Job and Trigger based on time value (future time). Scheduler will then schedule the Job in future. In this case, spawning so many schedulers will not create a problem? We need to also shutdown the scheduler, so how we will do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Scheduler that will run that task. There are tons of Scheduling APIs out there. you can use Quart or Obsidian scheduler.